# Revolution Slider: A way to snap to grid when adding text to a slide?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider, revolution-slider

I am able to add text without issue to the revolution slider but is there a way to force it to snap to the nearest coordinates, or center the text block on the slide without "eyeing" it up?

When you are dragging and dropping items like buttons, is there a way to set the exact coordinates of the button so it is consistent across slides. For example in some software you can hold CTRL while moving the mouse to see the grid lines and where the item will line up such as a ruler. I don't have a picture per se, but I am looking for a way to set items at the same point across slides without simply guessing.

I am using the latest version of the slider 5.x.

Comment: Difficult to understand really what is your problem. If is not to late, please could you provide some screenshots (before / after) of what you want, thanks.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec When you are dragging and dropping items like buttons, is there a way to set the exact coordinates of the button so it is consistent across slides. For example in some software you can hold CTRL while moving the mouse to see the grid lines and where the item will line up such as a ruler. I don't have a picture per se, but I am looking for a way to set items at the same point across slides without simply guessing. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes it have :) I know that you can display a grid and make it magnetic. You can find this in the main slide elements viewer. In the bottom bar you have 2 selectors: With the first one, "help Grid", you can chose the grid settings (25x25 or custom…) and with the second one, "Snap to" you can make it magnetic. Just try it…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Great I will take a look right now.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Found it! Please make this an answer so I can give you the credit. I will include a screenshot for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a Helper Grid in Slider Revolution plugin.

It is located in the main items slide viewer (visual) editor, just at the bottom. You have 2 selectors:

- Help Grid: You can chose between 25x25, 50x50 or a custom helper grid.
- Snap to: You can make lines in this helper grid magnetic…

[image]